# Barcode scanning view

Tags: android

I have integrated a github library as a module in my project for qr code scanning and getting this type of view

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <com.notbytes.barcode_reader.camera.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.notbytes.barcode_reader.camera.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/graphicOverlay"
            android:background="#44000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.notbytes.barcode_reader.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

    <com.notbytes.barcode_reader.ScannerOverlay
        android:id="@+id/scan_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#44000000"
        app:line_color="#7323DC"
        app:line_speed="6"
        app:line_width="5"
        app:square_height="250"
        app:square_width="250" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I want a view something like this

[image]

I tried editing the source classes but not getting any change.

Comment: You have to customize this view according to your need.

Comment: Yup  I know and I tried too but no changes

Comment: Use this one https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Comment: Use zxing lib, in this, you may customize the UI

Comment: But zxing is deprecated

Comment: Who told you that Zxing is deprecated because its updated last 3 month so it might be old but code is updated?

Comment: I read somewhere

Comment: you have to modify it a bit to make it work

Comment: I want to know where to modify

Comment: why not use firebase here?

Comment: If you have good step step tutorial then it is much useful